# Find minimum date after maximum of different date

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have a table that contains all the dates of when a Gas supply was turned on or turned off.  I want to obtain the minimum date it was turned off, between the most recent turn on date and the next turn on date before that, and the minimum date it was turned on, between the most recent turn off date and the next turn off date before that.  I also want it to ignore the lines where the date for on and off is the same. (Not even sure I'm explaining it properly it's become that convoluted in my head, sorry!)  Probably better showing examples than anything.

In image 1
I would want to return 02/11/2015 for the OFF and 23/12/2015 for the ON value.
[image: IMAGE1]

In Image 2
I want it to ignore the last two lines as they are the same date, and pull 28/07/2021 as OFF and 22/11/2021 as ON.
[image: IMAGE2]

In Image 3
I would want the date 13/08/2007 for when it was originally turned ON, and 26/06/2023 for the OFF Date.
[image: IMAGE3]

In Image 4
I would want the date 24/03/2011 for OFF and 11/04/2011 for ON.
[image: IMAGE4]

I have the data stored as per the images although they are all in the same table so each ID in those images are different but they are all in the one table.

Got as far as below then just lost it.  Hope someone can help.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.dbo.##tempROWS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE  ##tempROWS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
your text`ROW_NUM, ID, Date, Status
INTO ##TEMPROWS
FROM ##tempunion  ---the main table`

CREATE TABLE ##temptablefin  (
[RId]        int ,
[ID]   nvarchar(9),
    [Date]  datetime,
[Status]   nvarchar(12),
    [MAXOFFDATE] datetime NULL,
    [MAXONDATE] datetime NULL,
    [MinRowNo] int
)

INSERT INTO ##temptablefin
SELECT 
ROW_NUM AS RID, 
ID, Date, Status
, '01/01/1990' AS MAXOFFDATE
, '01/01/1990' AS MAXONDATE
NULL AS MinRowNo

FROM ##TEMPROWS

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.dbo.##mincount') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE  ##mincount;
Select MIN(Id) AS MINCount, ID , Status
INTO ##mincount 
FROM  ##temptablefin  GROUP BY ID, Status

UPDATE ##temptablefin 
SET MinRowNo = (SELECT MINCount FROM ##mincount mm WHERE mm.ID = ##temptablefin.ID and mm.Status =  ##temptablefin.Status)

select cc.ID, cc.Rid, cc.CertDate, cc.Status, cc.MAXOFFDATE, cc.MAXONDATE, cc.MinRowNo
,CASE WHEN cc.Status = 'ON' AND ff.Status = 'ON' THEN cc.Date ELSE ff.Date END AS ffs
,CASE WHEN cc.Status = 'CAPPED OFF' AND ff.Status = 'OFF' THEN cc.Date ELSE ff.Date END AS ffS2
,ff.Nid,ff.ID, ff.Date, ff.Status

from ##temptablefin cc
INNER JOIN (SELECT CASE WHEN (id) = MinRowNo THEN (id) Else (Rid+1) END AS Nid, ID, Status, CDate FROM ##temptablefin) ff
ON CC.RId = ff.Nid and cc.ID = ff.ID

ORDER BY cc.ID, cc.RId
```

Comment:  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data

Comment: Also use *code* blocks for code, not quite blocks; quote blocks are for quoting.

Comment: I can't make sense of the description and how that matches up with the examples.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find how to block code, it kept not letting me post, and I had no idea really what to put as the description as it's so convoluted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of this solution is the use of partition by Lead and Lag.  This allows looking at the next a previous values of a properly created record order within an id.  In part, the code looks for sequential events of OFF and ON pairs that contain the most recent off.  The Where clause at the end of the code removes all of the event that were related to generating the date pairs of interest.

The temptablefin table in my MS SQL SERVER

| RId | ID | Date | Status | MAXOFFDATE | MAXONDATE | MinRowNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10010040 | 2007-08-13 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 10010040 | 2008-07-17 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 10010040 | 2009-02-23 00:00:00.000 | OFF | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 10010040 | 2009-04-02 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | 10010040 | 2015-11-02 00:00:00.000 | OFF | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | 10010040 | 2015-12-23 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 7 | 10010040 | 2016-11-02 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 8 | 10071081 | 2021-07-28 00:00:00.000 | OFF | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 9 | 10071081 | 2021-11-22 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 10 | 10071081 | 2022-10-12 00:00:00.000 | OFF | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 11 | 10071081 | 2022-10-12 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 12 | 10140100 | 2007-08-13 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 13 | 10140100 | 2012-05-29 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 14 | 10140100 | 2018-07-26 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 15 | 10140100 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 16 | 10140100 | 2023-06-26 00:00:00.000 | OFF | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 17 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

```
WITH
data
as
(
SELECT  [RId]
      ,[ID]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Status],

     LAG(date,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID  ORDER BY DATE DESC,STATUS DESC) next_date,  -- if off status and part of an Off/On pair then next date is the on pair.
     LAG(id,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID  ORDER BY DATE DESC,STATUS DESC) next_id,  -- if at most recent link, the next_id is 0
      (CASE when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By ID Order by (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'ON' then 0 else 1 end) DESC ) = 1 and status='OFF' then 1 else 0 end)as recent_off,  -- retrieve most recent off, sort off higher than on
      MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID  ) MIN_ON ,  -- minimum date calculated for use in business rule case when the most recent event for id is OFF

      case when
       (
        LEAD(status,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID  ORDER BY DATE DESC,STATUS DESC) = 'OFF' and [Status] = 'ON'    -- the on is next to an off
        OR 
        LAG (status,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID  ORDER BY DATE DESC,STATUS DESC) = 'ON' and [Status] = 'OFF')   -- the off is next to an on
     
        AND NOT ( date = LEAD(date,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID  ORDER BY DATE DESC,STATUS DESC) or  date = LAG(date,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID  ORDER BY DATE DESC,STATUS DESC))  -- not on same day
     
          then 1  else 0 end off_on_pair  -- looking for OFF/ON pair that are adjacent but not on the same day


  FROM [dbo].[temptablefin]
)
,
get_id_pairs
as
(
Select
-- get pair of results   pr_id1 and pr_id2
ID,
 DATE  pr_id1,   -- always select the most recent off status for an ID
case when  next_id = 0  then MIN_ON 
                 when  off_on_pair = 1  then next_date
                 end pr_id2 -- select the other status pair of the following ON event or the first ON event if the Id is currently off
from
data
where
recent_off = 1 and date is not null
)

select
fin.*
from
[temptablefin] fin
inner join
get_id_pairs gp
on
fin.id = gp.id and
fin.date in (pr_id1,pr_id2)
```

Output:

| RId | ID | Date | Status | MAXOFFDATE | MAXONDATE | MinRowNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10010040 | 2015-11-02 00:00:00.000 | OFF | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | 10010040 | 2015-12-23 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 8 | 10071081 | 2021-07-28 00:00:00.000 | OFF | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 9 | 10071081 | 2021-11-22 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 12 | 10140100 | 2007-08-13 00:00:00.000 | ON | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 16 | 10140100 | 2023-06-26 00:00:00.000 | OFF | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but unfortunately this returned no results.

Comment: @Deb, I revisited the query and I have added the input data and query results to the example.

Comment: Thank you that has worked, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (
    select *,
         -- the defaults don't really matter much as long as they're impossible values
         lag("Date", 1, '19000101') over (partition by ID order by "Date", Status) as lagDate,
        lead("Date", 1, '20991231') over (partition by ID order by "Date", Status) as leadDate,
         lag(Status, 1, '<') over (partition by ID order by "Date", Status) as lagStatus,
        lead(Status, 1, '>') over (partition by ID order by "Date", Status) as leadStatus
    from T
), culled as (
    select *,
        max("Date") over (partition by ID) as maxDate,
        max(case when Status = 'OFF' then "Date" end) over (partition by ID) as maxOff
    from data
    where -- remove same-day events
        not ("Date" = lagDate  and Status <> lagStatus) and
        not ("Date" = leadDate and Status <> leadStatus)
)
select ID, 
    min(maxOff) as "Off",
    min(case when Status = 'ON' and ("Date" > maxOff or maxOff = maxDate) then "Date" end) as "On"
from culled
group by ID;
```

You seem to want to ignore the current status if it has most recently been turned off. Ignoring that, you appear to want the latest date it had been turned off with a subsequent (re)activation. And then you want the earliest "on" date corresponding to that "off" date.

I also found a clean gaps and island approach and it's probably more robust as well:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        max(Date) over (partition by ID) as maxDate,
        min(Status) over (partition by ID, Date) as minDailyStatus,
        max(Status) over (partition by ID, Date) as maxDailyStatus  
    from T
), culled as (
    select *,
        count(case when Status = 'Off' and Date <> maxDate then 1 end) over (
            partition by ID order by Date desc, Status desc
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as grp
    from data
    where minDailyStatus = maxDailyStatus -- only one status per date
)
select ID,
    min(case when Status = 'Off' then Date end) as "Off",
    min(case when Status = 'On'  then Date end) as "On"
from culled
where grp = 0
group by ID;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/h97SRS33?hide=60

Comment: Hi thanks for trying to help,  unforutunately both of those queries just returns each ID and then Null for On and Null for Off for each ID I'm afraid.

Comment: @Deb, if you follow the dbdiddle link you'll see that I duplicated all your sample data and that those queries return the requested values.

Comment: Sorry my error, made a silly mistake!  You are a genius thank you so much!  Spent hours on that, will have to now go look what that code does and learn, greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I wouldn't want to ignore the current status if it's been turned off, I have dates of 23/06/23 off and 16/08/22 off and it's pulling back 23/06/23 instead of the first time it went off (16/08/22) any ideas please, I'm using the first piece of code.

Comment: @Deb, I think it was the logic on sample #3 that throws me. If that matches up with what you're talking about would you be able to clarify why those two particular values are the ones selected?

Comment: yes those two are selected in that instance and are returning correct.  An ID has the potential to never have been turned off or never have been turned off.  The one not pulling correctly has never been on it has two off dates of 23/06/2023 and 16/08/2022 so the correct date would be the 16th.  Many thanks!  :)

Comment: @Deb, What would you want for an ID that had either all off or all on? And which two dates when there are more than two?

Comment: if they were all on or all off then the very first time they went off or on would be what I needed.  This is why it was so hard to define a title for the post.  Basically I need the earliest time it went Off, after the latest time it was On and the earliest time it went On after the latest time it went Off.  If it was always On or always Off then the earliest date it came On or Off.  For context this is actually about servicing boilers, I need to report if any were disconnected (Off) in the month, if any were reconnected (On) in the month and how many are disconnected in total...

Comment: ...the first criteria of "Off in the month" - if it actually was first turned off say 3 years ago then I don't want to report it as going off in this month, I only want those that went off (after it had been on) in this month. Opposite for On. Then I report how many are off in total, regardless of when they actually went off. We have tenants changing and financial circumstances changing so sometimes gas supplies are on and off all the time. Hope that all makes sense! Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I'm not particularly happy with these queries. #2 is probably working. #3 may be an alternative to what you want to achieve in a much simpler way. https://dbfiddle.uk/gjlEMu7M?hide=8184

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254541/discussion-between-deb-and-shawnt00).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just insert those on/off event dates to another table specific to this purpose?

By doing this you do not need to struggle filtering those dates.

So, you need to insert off date and first on day after off period.

Also, another solution can be like this. Add additional info date column to the table. Insert you off date, then when turning on from off update additional date of off record.

P.S: Personally, I do not prefer second one since it will introduce null values in additional date column.

Hope these ideas help.

Comment: How do I identify the correct on/off dates though?

Comment: You now the current state. If you don't know you may query from the DB.
If state is ON and you are setting to OFF you may run some logic vice versa. It is up to your algorithm skills.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-evaluated the question along with all the comments. My conclusion is that the essence of the problem is only just to identify transitions in status and then moreover to determine the dates of the most recent transition so that summary results can be calculated. There's also a minor snag in eliminating those dates where multiple transitions were record. (My guess is that those are probably from a shutoff followed an immediate payment to reactivate. The reason don't matter though.) The others answers are not so straightforward as this one and these queries should probably run faster against a large dataset.

To get details about the most recent change in account status use this:

```
with culled as (
    select ID, Date, min(Status) as Status,
        lead(min(Status), 1, 'XX') over (partition by ID order by Date desc) as prev_Status,
        lead(Date) over (partition by ID order by Date desc) as prev_Date
    from T
    group by ID, Date
    having min(Status) = max(Status)
), most_recent_transitions as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by Date desc) as rn,
        lead(Status, 1, 'XX') over (partition by ID order by Date desc) as prev_Status2,
        lead(Date) over (partition by ID order by Date desc) as prev_Date2  
    from culled
    where Status <> prev_Status
)
select ID, Date,
    case when Status = 'OFF' then prev_Date2 else prev_Date end as Date2,
    prev_Date as PreviousDate,
    concat(prev_Status, ' -> ', Status) as Transition,
    prev_Date2 as PreviousDate2,
    concat(prev_Status2, ' -> ', prev_Status) as PreviousTransition2
from most_recent_transitions
where rn = 1;
```

To get just the desired aggregates that were mentioned in a comment use this query:

```
with culled as (
    select ID, Date, min(Status) as Status,
        first_value(min(Status)) over (partition by ID order by Date desc) as mr_Status,
        lead(min(Status), 1, '') over (partition by ID order by Date desc) as prev_Status,
        lead(Date) over (partition by ID order by Date desc) as prev_Date
    from T
    group by ID, Date
    having min(Status) = max(Status)
), marked_transitions as (
    select *,  
        case when Status <> prev_Status then 1 end as transitioned,
        case when Date between '20230701' and '20230731' then 1 end as in_range
    from culled
)
select
    count(distinct case when Status = 'OFF'
                         and transitioned = 1 and in_range = 1 then ID end) as turnedOff,
    count(distinct case when Status = 'ON'
                         and transitioned = 1 and in_range = 1 then ID end) as turnedOn,  
    count(distinct case when mr_Status = 'OFF' then ID end) as currentlyDisconnected
from marked_transitions;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/wUov6v_t